# client denied by server configuration for amazon ec2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I am using apache 2.4 on amazon ec2.

I have server configuration in httpd.conf as below.

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But I am getting error AH01630: client denied by server configuration: in apache log console.

Also referfed too many article. They are giving same solution as above.

Please give me solution if any

Comment: Can you please show me your virtual host file.

Comment: I assume you've gone through the troubleshooting steps from here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration ?